# AWS: How do I programmatically add a role to an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I would like to add a role to an existing (running?) instance.  Is this possible programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible (not even in AWS dashboard). You can add an IAM role only when launching an instance

https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

> Q: Can I change the IAM role on a running EC2 instance? No, at this
>   time you cannot change the IAM role on a running EC2 instance. You can
>   change the permissions on the IAM role associated with a running
>   instance, and the updated permissions will take effect almost
>   immediately.

Comment: ah, perfect.  I've got a role associated with the instance, so I'll go that route.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can attach a role to Running instance from Console and from CLI as well

`aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id *InstanceId* --iam-instance-profile Name=*NewInstanceProfileName*`

**Official Announcment here**

> You can now attach or replace an AWS Identity and Access Management
>   (IAM) role to your existing Amazon EC2 instance. IAM roles enable your
>   applications running on EC2 to use temporary security credentials that
>   AWS creates, distributes, and rotates automatically. Using temporary
>   credentials reduces the risk of long-term key compromise.

For more information. [Click here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/new-attach-an-iam-role-to-your-existing-amazon-ec2-instance/)